# Classless CSS Tabbed Content using radio instead of unordered list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert the classless css and html below instead of list to use radio and labels for tabbed content.

Ideally it should be concise and not redundant and here's the setup of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<nav>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
    <label for="tab1">One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab2">Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab3">Three</label>
    <section id="tab2">Tab 2</section>
    <section id="tab3">Tab 3</section>
    <section id="tab1">Tab 1</section>
</nav>
```

Below is the tabbed content code that works with unordered list, I have not include any further styling just to show the bare bones:

```css
nav>ul~section:last-of-type{display:block;}
nav>ul~section:target~section:last-of-type{display:none;}
section:not(:target) {display:none;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">One</a>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Two</a>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Three</a>
    </ul>
    <section id="tab2">Tab 2</section>
    <section id="tab3">Tab 3</section>
    <section id="tab1">Tab 1</section>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am a bit unclear what your question is. Could you explain a bit more and show us what you have already tried. Also, does the CSS in your initial setup actually work as last-of-type selects on tags not other selectors AFAIK.

Comment: It's a tabbed content using ul li tags. I would like to replace it with radio buttons no additional ids and no classes. Yes, it works try it. I just included stack's fiddle for inline testing.

Comment: Just an observation - yes it works but the [id] are redundant (they are ignored).

Comment: I think you may find reading this link closely would help - it shows how to link labels and other elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Thanks for the link and yes you can ignore the redundant ids it works without it.

Comment: If you want a label after an input to be associated with an input that input has to have an id - so more ids would be needed if you definitely want that HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to have the HTML structure as given then you could do something like this without introducing any more classes or ids:

```css
section {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label[for="tab1"]~#content1 {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+label[for="tab2"]~#content2 {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+label[for="tab3"]~#content3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">One</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Two</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Three</label>
  <section id="content2">Tab 2</section>
  <section id="content3">Tab 3</section>
  <section id="content1">Tab 1</section>
</nav>
```

However, it's not very general (if you add another tab then the CSS has to be updated) and the labels are not linked to their inputs (so the user can't click on the word 'One' for example. To get that to work you'd have to put the id="tab1" in that input.

Comment: My initial solution is somehow similar, but using `nth-of-type` and without any specific ids, but it also piles up if you need to add more. Yes, it's not general as I'm looking for what the list method has achieved, but with radio buttons.

Comment: So, do you still have a problem? I’m not clear what you are looking for now.

Comment: Yes, still a problem as I am looking for a better solution like the ordered list and link method that I presented.

Comment: I should have set or use `tab` like the reference code instead of `content` in the ids, that was my mistake, sorry for the confusion. Edited it now.